# How to find device is touch or nontouch.?

Tags: blackberry

I want to make an application for both touch and non-touch device in blackberry.
I don't know how to find the device is touch or not.
Is there any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Touchscreen.isSupported();
```

This is used to find whether the device is touch or non-touch.
If the device is Touch then it returns

```
True
```

else it returns

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that for me, it was better to build the app to cope with both touch and nontouch phones. Remember that devices running firmware older than 4.7 can not load touch enabled apps.